# Bad Request for http.put() with request body

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using HttpClient from '@angular/common/http' and wanted to perform put operation.

My Angular code is like :

```
public updateDetails(data: Data) {


    const url = '/project/rest/v1/configuration/device/update'
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');


    let body = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this.http.put(url, data, { headers: headers })
      .map(response => true)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return Observable.of(false);
      });

  }
```

But, i am getting

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad
>   Request",

Please help me what i am missing. I tried to pass the data in stringfy format but that is also giving me same error.

Comment: Wait - the headers weren't there a minute ago! So the error exists with the headers?

Comment: HTTP Status 400 is quite generic and is reliant on the server configuration. This has to do with the server equally. Need to know server configuration and expectations.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i think i got the issue i am working on it.

Comment: You should just send the data object and let Angular serialize it for you. Don't `JSON.stringify()` it first.

Comment: @RandyCasburn is right, let Angular serialize the data for you. Also, add an "Accept" header with the expected media type. I have seen that sometimes incorrect headers and url also results in HTTP 400.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have two issues.

1. headers.append does not modify the headers object, it returns a new headers object with the header appended.

So, instead of

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
```

you should do

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
   .append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
```

---

2. You don't need to stringify the data -

just pass the object to the HttpClient,
as in:

```
this.http.put(url, data, { headers: headers })
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.put(url, data, options)
```